# Writing 2 new Columns to a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm attempting to add to columns to a 'CSV' file, I can copy from the previous CSV file but when I attempt to write the next 2 columns it only uses the last row to fill in for the rest of the rows, for `speed` and `wind_dirs`. The 2 figures are being created in a `for` loop before hand, should I store these in a list and then write from that? Any ideas would be great. Thanks

```
with open('latlon.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    with open('wind2.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
        towns_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel') # csv reader
        writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n') # csv writer
        for rows in towns_csv:
            x = float(rows[2]) #gets x axis
            y = float(rows[1]) # gets y axis
            url = ("http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?") #start of url string
            lat = "lat="+format(y) #creates the latititue part of the url string
            lon = "lon="+format(x) # creates the longitude part of the url string
            text = url + format(lat) + ";" + format(lon) #combines the strings together to create a new url
            response = requests.get(text) # get the url 
            xml_text=response.text # turns the requested url into a text file
            winds= bs4.BeautifulSoup(xml_text, "xml") #uses BeautifulSoup to make an xml file
            wind_all = winds.find_all("windSpeed") # finds the "windSpeed" element
            speed = wind_all[0].get("mps") # finds the first "mps" attribute
            wind_dir = winds.find_all("windDirection")# finds the "windDirection" element
            wind_dirs = wind_dir[0].get("deg") #finds the "deg" attribute
            new = []
            row = next(towns_csv)
            row.append(speed)
            row.append(wind_dirs)
            new.append(row)
            for item in towns_csv:
                item.append(speed)
                item.append(wind_dirs)
                new.append(item)
                writer.writerow(item)
```

Comment: This doesn't look right to me: `writer.writerow(rows + [speed] + [wind_dirs])`. Did you intend to write `row` (singular)? I'm struggling to picture the structure you're creating in that line of code, after the `zip` too, and unfortunately I can't run it myself to see how it plays out.

Comment: Your edit has now probably broken your code. You have nested `for rows`. EDIT: And now you've changed it back. I'm not making these comments to suggest that you keep editing - is your posted code an accurate representation of what you're using or not? That's the important part, nobody can help you debug if you keep changing it round.

Comment: The use of `writer.writerow` is correct. It expects a list, with each element in that list being a column of the output. Using `zip` and then concatenating the list inside that call feels clumsy and I think you're getting a malformed list but I can't test. Essentially, you're probably just looking to take a row from the previous csv (which will be a list) and just `extend` the extra columns to that list, then write it back.

Comment: That sounds like what I'm trying to do, but just making a very poor job of it, I'll try making a list and appending the 2 new things to the end of it. Thanks for the help I really do appreciate it.

Comment: So I've got it mostly figured out, I've edited the code above, the problem I'm having now is that it doesn't seem to iterate over the `speed` and `wind_dirs` and just uses the last figure from the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following adjustment including slight modifications of the string formatting and revamping of final lines of code. There is no need for the *row* or *new* lists and the last `for` loop. Simply append API data to the *rows* which are the lines of `latlong.csv` file and write it to new file, `wind2.csv`:

```
import csv
import requests
import bs4

with open('latlon.csv', 'r') as csvfile, open('wind2.csv', 'w') as csvoutput:
    towns_csv = csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel')    # csv reader
    writer = csv.writer(csvoutput, lineterminator='\n') # csv writer
    for rows in towns_csv:
        x = float(rows[2])                              # gets x axis
        y = float(rows[1])                              # gets y axis
        url = "http://api.met.no/weatherapi/locationforecast/1.9/?{0};{1}" # start of url string
        lat = "lat={}".format(y)                        # creates the latititue part of the url string
        lon = "lon={}".format(x)                        # creates the longitude part of the url string
        text = url.format(lat, lon)                     # combines the strings together to create a new url
        response = requests.get(text).text              # get the url into text format                           
        winds= bs4.BeautifulSoup(response, "xml")       # uses BeautifulSoup to make an xml file
        wind_all = winds.find_all("windSpeed")          # finds the "windSpeed" element
        speed = wind_all[0].get("mps")                  # finds the first "mps" attribute
        wind_dir = winds.find_all("windDirection")      # finds the "windDirection" element
        wind_dirs = wind_dir[0].get("deg")              # finds the "deg" attribute

        rows.append(speed)                              # append speed value
        rows.append(wind_dirs)                          # append wind value
        writer.writerow(rows)                           # write new row
```

**Input** *(latlon.csv)*

```
1   54  -122
2   53  -112
3   52  -102
```

**Output** *(wind2.csv)*

```
1   54  -122    1.3    16.2
2   53  -112      4   330.7
3   52  -102    4.9   314.1
```

Comment: Well that worked great, I don't know why I was trying to over complicate things. Thank you.